# Is ActiveRecord::Batches::find_each thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html.

Is the implementation of `find_each` thread-safe? In other words, can I do something like

```
count = 0
MyModel.find_each do |model|
    count += 1 if model.foo?
end
```

And expect it to be thread-safe?

Answer (score 11):

This question has been left unanswered for a while. I think it is a very good question, as problems of thread-safety like this one can be harmful to an application's integrity and since Rails feels so magical, it's good to always have a look under the hood and understand what's going on.

This method (`find_each`) would not be thread-safe in the specified case, if the state of the data can be changed during the execution of the code and affect the outcome. (e.g. block being called with removed data, block being called twice with the same data, and block skipping part of the data).

In summary, `find_each` **is not** thread-safe. It doesn't do any locking, so it **does not** ensure that the data has been removed, updated, inserted or moved by the time it calls the block. The only thing it ensures is that the block won't be called for the same primary index twice.

Here's an example where it could yield a weird result (stupid case though). Let's assume the following `Account` table:

```
|id|balance|
| 1|   1000|
| 2|    500|
| 3|   2000|
```

And the following code (let's use `batch_size: 1` since it's such a small table):

```
total = 0
Account.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1) |acc|
   total += acc.balance
end
```

On the first iteration, it would run the block with `Account(id: 1, balance: 1000)`, hence `total` would equal `1000`.
Now, while the second iteration is being run, another thread runs the following code:

```
Account.transaction do
    acc1 = Account.find(1).lock!
    acc3 = Account.find(3).lock!
    acc1.update(balance: acc1.balance + acc3.balance)
    acc3.update(balance: 0)
end
```

It basically transfers everything from account 1 to account 3. Now the table would look like:

```
|id|balance|
| 1|   3000|
| 2|    500|
| 3|      0|
```

But remember that we have already processed the first account, and it would keep running the block with the second account, so `total` would equal `1500`, and then finally run the block for the third account, since the balance is now `0`, the `total` would remain at `1500`.
This would cause you to have the `total` at `1500` when you're clearly trying to have it at `3500`.

(`each` is not completely thread-safe, but it guarantees this case)

---

If you need to ensure thread safety, a simple way is to get a lock on the table (for example, in postgres). Remember that getting a lock on the whole table can impact your performance a lot.

```
count = 0
MyModel.transaction do
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("LOCK TABLE mymodels SHARE")
   MyModel.find_each do |model|
       count += 1 if model.foo?
   end
end
```

Note that `MyModel.lock.find_each` is not thread-safe either.

---

`find_each` works by ordering everything by the primary index (usually `id`), and limiting the result with batch size (default is `1000`).

```
SELECT  "models".* FROM "models" WHERE "models"."id" > 1000) ORDER BY "models"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
```

It stores the last id in the batch, then calls the block for each row. Once the block is executed for every row, it runs another query with `models.id > last_id`, until it reaches the end.